# Getters and Setters in Swift

Tags: swift, getter-setter, computed-properties

Why do we need to use setters in the particular case below in Swift.

I'm trying to convert 'display.text' `String` to `Double`. I understand that getter brings back `String` value and converts it to `Double` and assigns this value to variable `newValue`.

Question: why we set display.text value back into `String` again using `= "\(newValue)"` if we just converted it into `Double`?

```
var doubleValue: Double {
    get {
        return NSNumberFormatter().numberFromString(display.text!)!.doubleValue
    }
    set {
        display.text = "\(newValue)"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I understand that getter brings back String value and converts it to Double and assigns this value to variable newValue.

This isn't correct. The getter just returns the double. There is no `newValue` in the getter.

In the setter, `newValue` is a shortcut for "the implied argument of the setter." The explicit syntax is this:

```
var doubleValue: Double {
    ...
    set(newValue) {
        display.text = "\(newValue)"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but why assign String "newValue" to display.text? Display.text was already a String before we converted it to a Double

Comment: Because this is the setter. What do you want to happen when someone sets the `doubleValue` property?

Comment: Thanks Rob, you helped a lot!

Answer (score 1):

In order to override setter and getter for swift variables use the below given code

```
var temX : Int? 
var x: Int?{

set(newX){

   temX = newX

}

get{

    return temX

}
```

We need to keep the value of variable in a temporary variable, since trying to access the same variable whose getter/setter is being overridden will result in infinite loops.

We can invoke the setter simply like this

```
x = 10
```

Getter will be invoked on firing below given line of code

```
var newVar = x
```